# I want to map my tkinter buttons to keys on the numberpad, What am I doing wrong please?

Tags: python, tkinter, keymapping

Python noob here,
I have a catalog of snacks from the vending machine, text to speech, and a back, next and current button.

I want to map my buttons to keys on the numberpad but it doesnt seem to be working. When the gui pops up, I can click the button and it will read the items on the list for me, but I want to be able to control it with the numberpad instead of using the mouse to click the buttons.

```
vl = ["donuts","cookies","spicy chips","mild chips","cheesy chips","mini donuts","Mrs. Freshlys Cupcakes","rubbery cake thing"]
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
cupo = vl[0] # cupo is current position, 0 is the first entry in the vl list
def current():
       global cupo # cupo was defined outside of the function, therefore we call global
       engine.say(cupo)
       engine.runAndWait()


def back():
        global cupo
        pos = vl.index(cupo)
        if pos == 0: # pos is position
                engine.say(cupo)
                engine.runAndWait()
        else:
                prepo = int(pos) - 1 # prepo is previous position
                cupo = vl[prepo]
                engine.say(cupo)
                engine.runAndWait()


def next():
        global cupo
        pos = vl.index(cupo)
        if pos == (len(vl) - 1):
                engine.say(cupo)
                engine.runAndWait()
        else:
                nexpo = int(pos) + 1 # nexpo is next position
                cupo = vl[nexpo]
                engine.say(cupo)
                engine.runAndWait()

print('\n'.join(map(str,vl)))

import tkinter
import sys




window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("GUI")

def vendy():
    tkinter.Label(window, text = "Vendy!").pack()

b1 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Back", command = back).pack()
b2 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Repeat", command = current).pack()
b3 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Next", command = next).pack()

bind('/',back.func)
bind('*',current.func)
bind('-',next.func)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Instead of `bind()` alone you need to bind to something. `window.bind()` and so on. Also `back.func` is not valid. Just `back` is fine. Also `next` is a built in name so chance the name of that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.bind('/', back)
window.bind('*', current)
window.bind('-', next)
```

An event parameter is passed to the functions so add an argument to them.

Example:

```
def back(event=None):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You not binding to anything specific. You need to bind to something. So in this case you want to bind to the root window so the key event is always detected.

You will also need to change how you call the functions in the bind. `back.func` is not correct. Instead just use `back`.

Next change the name of your function `next` as this is already a build in name for Python so you are overwriting this useful method.

Next each of those functions will need to take at least one argument to handle the event that is sent to the function from the bind. If you need to also call that function from some other place without sending an argument you can use `event=None` to handle anything that calls the function.

Next place all your imports at the top. You should always keep you imports at the top.

Here is a cleaned up version of your code:

```
import tkinter
import pyttsx3
# import sys  # this import is not used.


vl = ["donuts", "cookies", "spicy chips", "mild chips", "cheesy chips",
      "mini donuts", "Mrs. Freshlys Cupcakes", "rubbery cake thing"]

engine = pyttsx3.init()
cupo = vl[0]  # cupo is current position, 0 is the first entry in the vl list


def current(event=None):
    global cupo  # cupo was defined outside of the function, therefore we call global
    engine.say(cupo)
    engine.runAndWait()


def back(event=None):
    global cupo
    pos = vl.index(cupo)
    if pos == 0:  # pos is position
        engine.say(cupo)
        engine.runAndWait()
    else:
        prepo = int(pos) - 1  # prepo is previous position
        cupo = vl[prepo]
        engine.say(cupo)
        engine.runAndWait()


def next_func(event=None):
    global cupo
    pos = vl.index(cupo)
    if pos == (len(vl) - 1):
        engine.say(cupo)
        engine.runAndWait()
    else:
        nexpo = int(pos) + 1  # nexpo is next position
        cupo = vl[nexpo]
        engine.say(cupo)
        engine.runAndWait()


def vendy():
    tkinter.Label(window, text="Vendy!").pack()


print('\n'.join(map(str, vl)))
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("GUI")
tkinter.Button(window, text="Back", command=back).pack()
tkinter.Button(window, text="Repeat", command=current).pack()
tkinter.Button(window, text="Next", command=next_func).pack()
window.bind('/', back)
window.bind('*', current)
window.bind('-', next_func)
window.mainloop()
```